# Determining the bounds of a joint distribution's double integral

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Say there are two continuous random random variables $X$ and $Y$ and I want to find $P(X>Y)$

I know that $P(X>Y)=\int_{o}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x}f_{xy}(x,y)dydx$

but could I also say that $P(X>Y)=\int_{y}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f_{xy}(x,y)dydx$

Reason being that since $X>Y$, $y$ can be any value but when we integrate with respect to $x$, we want to integrate over values greater than $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second equation should be written as $P\{X>Y\}=\int_0^{\infty} \int _y ^{\infty} f_{xy} (x,y) \, dx \, dy$. What you have written  makes RHS  dependent on $y$, but it is supposed to be a constant.

Comment: Sorry, but why does $y$ need to be constant?

Comment: Also, I thought that when it came to joint distributions, order of the integrals does not matter. Is this false?

Comment: @Christopher When there are limit of integration you have to write double integrals in carefully. The expression you have written is not correct. The formula $\int \int f(x,y)\, dx\, dy =\int \int f(x,y)\, dy\, dx$ is correct only when the integrals  are over the whole space.

Comment: Forgive me as I am still a novice at probability, but I just can't seem to figure out why one order of integrals work but the other doesn't. Could you further elaborate or is there a resource online I could take a look at to understand this?

Comment: @Christopher The notation $\int_{y}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f_{xy}(x,y)dydx$ is understood to stand for integrating first w.r.t. $y$ and then  w.r.t. $x$. If you do this you will end up with something that depends on $y$ instead a fixed number, right? .

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Out of curiosity, is the integral I have with $y$ on the outer integral meaningless or does it have a use as well i.e. does it represent anything in probability?